# Globally suppress c# compiler warnings

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, suppress

In my app I have a fair number of entities which have fields which are getting their values set via reflection. (In this case NHibernate is setting them). I'd like to get rid of the "x is never assigned to and will always have its default value 0" warnings, so I can more easily pick out the other warnings. I realize you can surround them in pragma directives, but AFAIK you have to do this for each one. Is there a project wide or solution wide way I could do this?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just put #pragma warning disable 169 at the top of the source code file?  It suppresses for the remainder of the file.

Comment: ++ to that, much better since it makes it clear that this file contains loads of these and not absolutely everything

Comment: In my case I'm using NHibernate to set the IDs of entities. So on every domain object I have private int _ID; I really don't want to have to set put pragma directives on each of the entites, but would rather something global.

Comment: ^^^ not only you ***should*** put the pragma directive in each entity, you should actually enable it and disable it on each individual offending assignment in each entity. Stop confusing "less typing" with convenience.  Any convenience earned by less typing is paid for later with much more inconvenience and weeping and gnashing of teeth.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the C# commandline option /nowarn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f28x9z3(VS.80).aspx

To do this within visual studio goto **Project properties->Build->(Errors and warnings) Suppress Warnings** and then specify a comma separated list of warnings which need to be suppressed.

Comment: As AnthonyWJones points out below, the compiler warning IDs you need to put into this comma separate list are found in the Output window while viewing the Build stream.What isn't mentioned yet in this thread is that they come in the form `CSxxxx` and you must remove the 'CS' prefix in your listed codes in order for it to work.

Comment: This was hard to find in VS2017.  In the menu bar choose **Project->(project name) Properties...**  Choose **Build** tab.  Look under **Errors and warnings** for **Suppress warnings:**  Add the warning numbers in that box.

Comment: Comma or semicolon. Don't forget to restart Visual Studio!

Answer (score 12):

Open the project properties, on the build tab, enter warning IDs you want to surpress in the Suppress warnings: box.

Comment: That is what I want to do but sadly warning ID's not written with warning in VS2010's error list pane.And some warning IDs are very close but codes are diffrent,I mean CLS error for int and CLS error for a Class name are diffrent.If your coding standart is not CLS what will you do?

Comment: @DavutGürbüz:  Trying looking in the output window when building

Comment: I opened detailed build so its hard to see, but it works, BC40028 disabled most of my CLS warnings thanks

Comment: Is there a programmatic way to suppress errors/warnings?

Answer (score 1):

The VC++ XML tag for this is <DisableSpecificWarnings/> with a semi-colon separated list of numeric IDs.
This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere that I can see but FYI.

Answer (score 1):

At least in VS2019, you can control solution-level (truly, it's directory-level) warnings in the `Directory.Build.Props` file by adding the following at the `<Project>` level:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <NoWarn>MSB3270;MSD3246</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This answer is the one I'm looking for. I don't have Visual Studio installed and need to suppress warnings, so source-level methods are the only way.