# C# disable warning

Tags: c#, suppress-warnings

Is there a way in code to disable certain warnings in C# alike #pragma warning(cmd: warningsNo) in c++?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526443/globally-suppress-c-sharp-compiler-warnings) for disabling a warning in an entire project (link for the benefit of future googlers)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Almost precisely [the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning) directive.

Answer (score 5):

To disable a warning you can use `#pragma`. For example, add the following line just before the code in question:

```
#pragma warning disable RCS1194
```

The preceding example disables the warning RCS1194 which is "Implement exception constructors."

To enable the warning again, add the following after the code in question:

```
#pragma warning restore RCS1194
```

If you have more than one warning, use a comma separated list. For example:

```
#pragma warning disable RCS1021, RCS1102, RCS1194
```

Although [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#pragma-warning) states that the prefix `CS` is optional, the prefix `RCS` is not optional. I believe this also applies for other prefixes. My recommendation would be to always use the prefix to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning) for the complete reference.