# How to disable specific warnings for the entire solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Globally suppress c# compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526443/globally-suppress-c-sharp-compiler-warnings)

To not add to each file a line like:

```
#pragma warning disable 1573
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All compilation options are specified on the project level. MSBuild exists below the level of solutions.

To do it for each project, go to the Build tab in Project Properties and enter the warning number in the Suppress Warnings textbox.

Comment: That is per project, not for the entire solution. As far as I can tell, there's no way to do it on the solution level.

Comment: @BigEndian: Correct; all compilation options are specified on the project level.  MSBuild exists below the level of solutions.

Comment: so if I have 200+ projects?

Comment: Use e.g. Notepad++ replace <NoWarn></NoWarn> in all project files with <NoWarn>CS1591,CS1572,CS1573</NoWarn> (or whatever you want). Assuming you don't want different suppression in every project.

Comment: same here, too many projects to do this individually. In 2019 there is this %(DisableSpecificWarnings) common variable - but I can't figure out how to change that one.

Comment: You can do this by adding Directory.Build.props file in the root of your solution and add this content to it , `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <NoWarn>CS1591</NoWarn>
 </PropertyGroup>`