# Getting rid of the warning message - the proper way

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, oracle-pro-c

I am working on a legacy pro* C/C++ code and migrated the project to Visual Studio 2015. When I compile the code in VS, it is giving me a below warning message at more than 100 places.

```
warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned short', possible loss of data
```

and the corresponding code is

```
stmt.len = strlen((char*)stmt.arr); // VARCHAR stmt[500];
```

I was planning to change the above code to

```
stmt.len = static_cast<unsigned short>(strlen((char *)stmt.arr));
```

this will just remove the warning message. But I have to modify in more than 100 places. Is there any way to get rid of this warning message may be using some sort of macro? 
Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: @NJMR  If you may then just redeclare the data member stmt.len  as having the type size_t.:)

Comment: Change the type of the `len` member?

Comment: And C-style casts like you do with `(char*)stmt.arr` is usually a sign you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: VARCHAR is a pro* C/C++ datatype. I cannot modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch off the warning with

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4267)
```

although, personally, I'd work through the errors and fix correctly. Your idea with `static_cast` isn't a bad one, and there is no danger of undefined behaviour with overflow as you're using `unsigned` types.

Finally, note that using a macro to replace a standard library function is *undefined behaviour*. Don't do that.

Comment: you deserve one too :)

Comment: But I have to chagne in more than 100 places. Is there a way to replace strlen using a macro to return unsigned short.?

Comment: @Bathsheba No! you were faster than me! that's all, you should be first

Comment: @HJMR here a solution to that (official) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx (other thread) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884331/how-to-disable-specific-warnings-for-the-entire-solution

Answer (score 1):

It's the right way to use `size_t` consistently. Or, there do the casting that you though as an update.

A work around for C4267 warnings and how to disable them also suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6836cc74-8890-4ca7-90ae-39c6723b02f5/is-there-smart-way-to-fix-many-c4267-warning-conversion-from-sizet-to-int-or-other-types?forum=vclanguage) is:

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4267)
```

For the macro #define (only a sample)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define strlen(x) static_cast<unsigned short>(strlen((char *)x)) 
//I tested with ((char *)x+1) and ((char *)x+2) for variation

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char stmt[] = "something";
    int len = strlen((char*)stmt); // VARCHAR stmt[500];
    cout << len;
    return 0;
}
```

Test [here](https://ideone.com/1DQovh) with IDEONE

Comment: nope & thanks. I also saw that you answered much faster than me :D

Comment: @oetoni: So I added this. #define strlen(x) static_cast<unsigned short>(strlen((char *)x)). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you really shouldn't do a macro with #define. as @Barthsheba said is not a defined/documented solution for your scenario but is your choice...if you choose to do so then you are right on the macro definition. That would do the trick. I am adding the code sample and test to my answer