# Suppressing warnings for solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I can't seem to be able to suppress warnings in my solution in Visual Studio 2017 by going into **Project Settings > Build > Suppress warnings**:

[image]

Even when I clean - build, rebuild, etc... the solution, Visual Studio keeps bringing up these warnings for me.

I brought this up with [a visualstudio.com report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/224196/suppress-warnings-from-project-settings-build-does.html) yesterday and it's "triaged" at the moment. Is there an alternative way to suppress warnings in the solution, without marking every single reference?

Version: 15.6.2

**Update:**
This is wierd.
Visual Studio 2017 uses a semicolon by default, but comma worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually use [pragma directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning):

```
#pragma warning disable 1591 
// whatever member is lacking xml comments, or even the whole file
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

Verbatim from the link above:

> disable:  Do not issue the specified warning message(s).

If you really want to disable warnings solution-wide, [there's no way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884331/how-to-disable-specific-warnings-for-the-entire-solution).

> All compilation options are specified on the project level. MSBuild exists below the level of solutions.

**But it can be done project-wise**, just like you were doing above; the only thing I would change is separating those codes using a comma and not a semicolon like in your picture (and without a comma in the end), e.g.:

```
1591,1701,1702,1705
```

That's because compiler options [use a comma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/nowarn-compiler-option).

Comment: MSDN specifies this under C/C++, does this apply to C#?

Comment: Yep. Try it and if it works mark my answer as solution :D

Comment: Sorry, is this placed inline? How can I do this for whole solution?

Comment: Whole solution - I don't know. Whole files, yes you can, just put it the first line at the beginning of the file andthe second at the end

Comment: Unfortunately, that's my real question: A way to deal with this solution-wise. Thanks tho.

Comment: For "my" Visual Studio it is a `;` rathern than `,` - Maybe depending on Version and/or locale.

Answer (score 9):

The way I do it solution-wide is to create a specific suppression file, for instance `GlobalSuppressionsForTestProjects.cs`, in a convenient solution-level location.

Then for each project of the solution where I want the suppression definitions applied, I add a link to the suppression file:

- right-click on project -> Add -> Existing Item
- in selection dialog, navigate to the suppression file
- click on `Add as Link`

[image: Add existing item as link]

I learned this trick from [this post](https://intellitect.com/making-sense-of-assemblyversion-numbers/) where the same way was applied for `AssemblyInfo.cs` files.

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to restart Visual Studio.  This worked for me, and FYI we do not need to include the CS part of the error in your textbox (it would still work as written though, but you only need the number for this.)  You have certainly restarted VS in the years since first asking the question, but for anyone having this problem today, I hope this helps.
I had the same issue with the same warning (CS1591).  So for "Suppress warnings" in the properties to actually work (rather than the #pragma solution which is a legitimate work-around but might be unnecessary keyboard time after a restart) you might just need to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I wouldnt downvote this. Simply because VS doesn't recognize the change right way if you have those error codes in your error list. But rebuilding has the same effect. It will clear those codes once put in project settings like OP was doing.